# Visual Studio Code OSX Snippets Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a MacBook Pro and and iMac, with the same version of Visual Studio Code installed on both.  And on both I'm experiencing the same problem.  Intellisense stops recognizing my user-made snippets at some point and I have to do a restart (which sometimes doesn't work).

I'm not using an extension for the snippets, but am manually entering them in preferences > user snippets, in the appropriate languages.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: If this is a marketplace extension that gives you OSX snippets, it's best to put link to specific one in your question. There may be different similar ones and it'll clarify things. Also check to see if it's on github and see if there are bugs logged for it. You may find a work around that way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my question to be more clear